# 3 Column layout with 1 column inside the middle column + RWD

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to accomplish this layout in CSS. I can get the left side of my example below just fine with a float right, however I'm trying to work it out so with responsive web design at a smaller screen size I get the result on the right.

[image: http://imgur.com/YYrWO]

Perhaps it's been a bit of a long day but I can't seem to get an idea of how to accomplish this. My main puzzle is getting the purple box from TOP RIGHT in full screen to BOTTOM at smaller screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any code that we can look at ?
You can read about `@media` css property:
https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/

This way you can customize your responsive design depending on the screen size.

This solution should resolve your problem,

https://jsfiddle.net/7nshG/1/

You should give `position:relative` to the container, and

```
position:absolute; 
bottom:0;
```

to the child div.

Comment: No code as I'm trying to figure out how to approach this. I know how to work media-screen. The main issue I'm getting is making the purple box go from top right to bottom center.

Comment: That fiddle doesn't work for me... the blue box contains text and because of the absolute positioning the text goes under the purple box.

Comment: there was a mismatch in the color and the name of the div try this [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7nshG/2/)

Comment: If you would like to prevent this problem to happen then you probably should add another div in the lightBlue div give it same width and some height under it blue div will go abut not sure to make it stick to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways. Assuming you're not designing from mobile first (and you're using floats to achieve the layout), then code the layout exactly to meet your desktop specs.

At the mobile breakpoint, set each element to 100% width. The content in the lightblue container will push the purple box down the page. If you coded the desktop layout with floats, you may need to resort to clearing but I doubt it. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bresson/7nshG/13/

```
.container {
    max-width:300px
}
#blue {
    border-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width:100%;
}
#blue p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#lightBlue {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-color: lightBlue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
#purple {
    border-color: purple;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}
```